# Skip % in R when using sprintf

Tags: r, printf

I am using "sprintf" function in R to generate some numbers as for a ggplot lables. The problem is that I want those numbers in percentage like the following:

```
sprintf("paste(round(%s*100, 2), '\\%', sep='')", data_plot[1])
```

As you can see I am using "\" so the sprintf function does not deal with it as a special character but I still receive the following error:

```
Error in sprintf("paste(round(%s*100, 2), '%', sep='')", names(data_plot [1]) : too few arguments
```

When I replace the "%" with for example "+" everything works fine. I found some posts regarding this and how I can write a separate function to take care of this, but I am wondering if there is an easier way of doing it.

**Note:** This line of code is a part of ggplot code so it has to be written like this.

Thanks

Comment: try something like `sprintf("%.2f%%", 1.235*100)`

Comment: You need to use "%%" in sprintf to print a single "%"

Comment: I'd be surprised if you got anything useful with quotes surrounding the `paste` function-call.

Comment: @BondedDust Actually it works just fine. I replaced % with %% and it worked.

Comment: @scribbles go ahead and write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it because that's what I ended up doing. Thanks

Comment: @nimafl: Perhaps it "works" and returns something that I would not expect that you actually desired:   This: `sprintf("paste(round(%s*100, 2), '%%', sep='')", 1.44444)` returns: `"paste(round(1.44444*100, 2), '%', sep='')"`.

Comment: @BondedDust Actually since this line is a part of ggplot it gives me the correct answer. But thanks for reminding me that, now I have to edit my question.

Comment: I think that is only likely to be useful inside selected portions of the hadleyverse. I also think that moving the `round` and `"*"` operations to the second argument would make this clearer. Then you don't need that whole `paste`-contraption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `"%%"` in `sprintf` to print a single `"%"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `paste` or `sprintf`, you don't need both.  So, something like

```
dat <- data.frame(x=seq(0.01, 1, len=10), y=runif(10))

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=dat$x, labels=sprintf("%.2f%%", 100*dat$x))
```

[image]

Comment: I had to use both in this case since the name of columns is variable and might change each time that I am calling that line of code.

Comment: @nimafl just use `dat[, variable]` in that case